# jspdf output is getting blank pdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, yii

I have the large amount of data from the table,and I am displaying the data in tables and when I want to convert the tales in to pdf and I did as follows

```
$("#btnPdf").click(function(){    
          var dt    = new Date();
          var day   = dt.getDate();
          var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
          var year  = dt.getFullYear();
          var hour  = dt.getHours();
          var mins  = dt.getMinutes();
          var postfix = month + "-" + day + "-" + year + "_" + hour + ":" + mins;
          var docs = 'ltr_'+ postfix;
          var w = 1000;
          var h = 1000;
          var div = document.querySelector('#divtoconvert');
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.width = w*2;
          canvas.height = h*2;
          canvas.style.width = w + 'px';
          canvas.style.height = h + 'px';
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          context.scale(2,2);
          var count = document.getElementById('count').value;
          var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', "a4");
          doc.deletePage(1);
          for(var j=1;j<=count;j++)
          { 
              html2canvas(document.getElementById("tbl-data"+j), {
                  useCORS: true,
                  allowTaint: true,
                  letterRendering: true,
                  scale: 2,
                  canvas: canvas,
                  onrendered: function(canvas) {
                      var width = canvas.width;
                      var height = canvas.height;
                      var millimeters = {};
                      millimeters.width = Math.floor(width * 0.264583);
                      millimeters.height = Math.floor(height * 0.264583);
                      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);
                      doc.addPage(millimeters.width, millimeters.height);
                      doc.addImage(imgData, 'png',0,0);
                  },
              }); 
         }

          setTimeout(function() {
              //jsPDF code to save file
              doc.save(docs+'.pdf');
          }, 2000); 
      });
```

I have retrieved the data in loop and I have showed each row as table in html and all is doing good for low data from the database. But I  have the 115 rows in the database, for this the pdf's are displaying as empty, don't know why it is happening?
  Here count is equals to 115 rows and 'tbl-data' is the id of the each table.
Please suggest me the right path, thanks in advance.